# insert command OLE parameterized

Tags: vb.net, oledb

CURRENT PROGRESS TOWARD SOLUTION:

This is the updated code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Strings (String_Name, Long_Text, Short_Text, Alternate_Text, Multi_String_ID, Lang_ID) VALUES (?,?, ?,?,?,?)"

Dim command = New OleDbCommand(sql, pConn)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webStringName", "String_Name")
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webLang_String", "Long_Text")
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptsShortText", "Short_Text")
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webAltText", "Alternate_Text")
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webMultiStringID", "Multi_String_ID")
```

Changed above line to this...
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webMultiStringID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = webMultiStringID

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webLang_Code", "Lang_ID")

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

ORIG POST:

I am trying to create and INSERT statement with and OLE adapter. I had it working without paramtersm but now I am trying to add parms and am having issues with the syntax. Ha

Here is the code so far...

```
command = New OleDbCommand(sql, pConn)

sql = "INSERT INTO Strings (String_Name, Long_Text, Short_Text) VALUES (?,?, """ & ptsShortText & """)"


command.Parameters.Add("@webStringName", OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "String_Name")
command.Parameters.Add("@webLang_String", OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Long_Text")

command = New OleDbCommand(sql, pConn)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Was just trying to get the first two variables parameterized.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed SQL

Comment: Why not go all the way and parameterize all three parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something wrong. You first add the parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@webLang_String", OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Long_Text")
```

and *then* replace the command with a new one (with no parameters):

```
command = New OleDbCommand(sql, pConn)
```

Thus, you remove all your existing parameters in this line. That's why it doesn't work.

---

You have to do it in the correct order:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Strings (String_Name, Long_Text, Short_Text) " & _
      "VALUES (?,?, """ & ptsShortText & """)"

Dim command = New OleDbCommand(sql, pConn)  ' First create the command

' Then add the parameters to the command
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webStringName", "String_Name")
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webLang_String", "Long_Text")

' Then execute the command. (DON'T recreate it with New OleDbCommand here,
' that would throw away all you've done so far.)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: @marc11h: Yes, and I'm trying to tell you what you did wrong and *why* it doesn't work. ;-) I've expanded my answer to show you a working solution.

Comment: I am getting only one error msg now: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. There is only one integer in the list. I will update my original code.

Comment: @marc11h: If you declare a parameter as an Integer, you cannot assign a String to it (at least not without converting the string into an integer first). Maybe it would be easiest if you specified in your question: (a) what data types your database fields have and (b) what .NET data types your variables (e.g. `webMultiStringID`) have. The data types must match.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you for your help. I had to assigned the value to the variables. I update my post to reflect the fix.